# Why setImageResource need different array to print images and how remainder work in images?

Tags: android, arrays

```
package com.example.imageview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static ImageView saadaimageview;
        private static Button saadabutton;
        private static int currentimageindex;
        int[] naviimages = {
            R.drawable.hhsd,
            R.drawable.second,
            R.drawable.third
        };


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            saadaimagelistener();
        }
        public void saadaimagelistener() {
            saadaimageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ourfirstimage);
            saadabutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            saadabutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    currentimageindex++;
                    currentimageindex = currentimageindex % naviimages.length;
                    saadaimageview.setImageResource(naviimages[currentimageindex]);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Please explain the above code current image index, how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of drawables :

```
int[] naviimages = {
    R.drawable.hhsd,
    R.drawable.second,
    R.drawable.third
};
```

Every time you click on the `saadButton`, the `currentimageindex` increase by 1

```
currentimageindex++;
```

the value of `currentImageIndex` take the rest of `currentimageindex` divided by the length of the drawable `array`

```
currentimageindex = currentimageindex % naviimages.length;
```

**Example :**

`currentimageindex  = 1;` and `naviimages.length = 3`

**then :**

`currentimageindex` will take 1 (the rest of 1 / 3)

So the `saadaimageview` will take `R.drawable.hhsd` as Image resource

Comment: But currentimageindex will start from 0

Comment: `currentimageindex++;` it will make it 1 at the first click